# If $f$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z_{0}$ then there exists $g$ with a simple zero such that $g^{m}=f$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following claim: Suppose $f$
  is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z_{0}\in\mathbb{C}$
  and $z_{0}$
  is a zero of order $m$
  of $f$
 . Then there exists a function $g$ which is
  holomorphic in the same neighborhood of $z_{0}$
  such that $z_{0}$
  is a simple zero of $g$
  and there exists a neighborhood of $z_{0}$ in which $g^{m}=f$.

I haven't really made any progress so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write $f(z) = (z-z_0)^m\cdot h(z)$ with $h(z_0) \neq 0$. Can you see how that helps?

Comment: The statement should be "in some neighborhood of $z_0$", not "in the same neighborhood".  It must certainly be a neighborhood in which all zeros of $f$ have order divisible by $m$.  Simply connected might also help.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: You're right of course, I will correct the question.

Comment: Still not right.  If $g$ was defined in the same neighborhood $U$ (and $U$ was connected), then having $g^m = f$ in a neighborhood of $z_0$ would imply that $g^m = f$ on all of $U$.

Comment: So what would be the correct phrasing?
That $g$ is holomorphic in some neighborhood of $z_{0}$ and in that neighborhood $g^{m}=f$?

Does it require a simply connected neighborhood for the claim to be true in the original neighborhood or is path connected sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $f$ can be expressed as
$$
f(z)=(z-z_0)^mh(z),
$$
where $h$ is holomorphic and non-vanishing in the domain $U$. Let $D\subset U$ be a disk centered at $z_0$. For $z\in D$ set
$$
\ell(z)=\int_{z_0}^z \frac{h'(\zeta)}{h(\zeta)},
$$
with the integration along the segment from $z_0$ to $z$, which lies entirely in $D$, and $k(z)=\exp\big(\frac{1}{m}\ell(z)\big)$. Then
$$
f(z)=h(z_0)(z-z_0)^m\big(k(z)\big)^m=\big(\zeta_0(z-z_0)k(z)\big)^m=\big(g(z)\big)^m,
$$
where $\zeta_0$ am $m-$th root of $h(z_0)$. Clearly, $g$ has the required properties.

Comment: Why does $h(z)=h(z_0)k(z)^m$?

Answer (score 1):

By the condition, $f(z)=(z-z_0)^mh(z)$ where $h$ is holomorphic in the given neighbourhood $U$ of $z_0$ and $h(z_0)\ne 0$.
Now for your desired result it is necessary and sufficient to find holomorphic $k$ with $h(z)=k(z)^m$. While this is possible in *some* neighbourhood of $z_0$ it is not necessarily possible in the given neighbourhood $U$, namely if $h(z)=0$ for some $z\in U$ (i.e. $f(z)=0$ for some $z\in U\setminus\{z_0\}$).

Comment: How does one prove the part about $h(z)=k(z)^m$ in some neighborhood of $z_{0}$?

Comment: @Serpahimz You should know where $z\mapsto z^{1/m}$ or $z\mapsto \exp(\frac1m\ln z)$ is holomorphic